# Is there a way to identify remotely that shutdown required for updates to apply?

Tags: windows, remote, update

Is there a way to remotely find out if a Windows Server (2003, 2008) has downloaded the Microsoft Windows updates and is just waiting for the user to confirm "**Install Updates and Shutdown**"?

I saw an excellent similar post, but it didn't specifically identify those updates where SHUTDOWN is required.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using WSUS to manage windows update deployments there are a bunch of ways to find out which updates are needed and the status of each update.  [This example](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/09/17/3474980.aspx) at the very bottom provides a detailed list of updates for a computer and their current status (Needed, Downloaded, Installed, etc.).

Secondly, you could create a PowerShell script to communicate with the PCs in your domain and find out if they are pending a reboot after installing updates.

[Overview from MSDN about Pending Reboots](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hansr/archive/2006/02/17/patchreboot.aspx)

[PowerShell Sample](http://www.techmumbojumblog.com/?p=375)

Comment: Thanks.  I found a vbs script that identifies the "reboot" required already, and that works great.  What I needed was identification of "Shutdown" required.  Any ideas on that one?